# Perl push into a sorted array

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

Consider the data block below, how can I maintain sorted the array by the 3rd field, and keep pushing items?

```
$VAR1 = [
          '1111',
          'http://...',
           3       #this is one of the 3rd field mentioned above
        ];
$VARN = [
           '5555',
           'http://...',
            0
        ];
```

My code looks like:

```
my @curItem = ($item->{id}, $item->{href}, getTotal( $item->{id}) );
push @items, \@curItem;
```

I've found [this](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Tie%3a%3aArray%3a%3aSorted) module which is similar to what I need.

*Any help appreciated.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use that module, you just need to supply the sort:

`tie @a, "Tie::Array::Sorted", sub { $_[0]->[2] <=> $_[1]->[2] };`

(Or something along those lines ... I'll have to check it. Basically, you need to sort based on the element of the array ref you're passing in)

**Edit:** Yup, this works for your data. Just checked it:

```
use Tie::Array::Sorted;

tie @a, "Tie::Array::Sorted", sub { $_[0]->[2] <=> $_[1]->[2] };

push @a, [ "1111", "http:// ...", 3];
push @a, [ "5555", "http:// ...", 0];

foreach $ref (@a)
{
    print $ref . "\n";
    print "@$ref \n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
ARRAY(0x9130888)
5555 http:// ... 0
ARRAY(0x90dd818)
1111 http:// ... 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, push is going to append the item to the end of the list no matter what.  It's a stack operation.  I'd say you'd probably be better off using a different data structure, such as a hash and then only sorting by key or value when necessary.  Without more details of what you're trying to write, its hard to say.

Otherwise, you'll need to write a subroutine which searches the list for the best insert place then uses splice to inject the item into place.  This sounds more like what you want to do, but I'm not sure its going to be particularly efficient, as you have to search the list for the insert point each time you want to add an item while maintaining a sorted order.

Comment: Agreed. The question is asking for something logically inconsistent; you can't both keep an array in a particular sorted order *and* `push` onto it because `push`, by definition, stores the items based on the order they were added, not based on their contents. As for the efficiency of doing sorted inserts, sorting data on insertion is one of the fastest ways to sort it, plus it avoids the need to re-sort every time you access the data, so it would be a win over sort-on-access in the overwhelming majority of cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you're adding more than one array reference to @items, add the references first, then use a Schwartzian Transform to perform a single sort operation:

```
@items = map $_->[1], sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } map { [ $_->[2], $_ ] } @items;
```

Randal wrote a column about this: http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/UnixReview/col64.html